# how to implement script that checks if there are files in folder periodically on server

Tags: php

I need code in php that periodically checks folder on server if there are any files in it so I can start some operations on files. Can someone give me some hints and starters where to look how to achieve this.

Thank you

Comment: You could do this with a cron job.

Comment: You should look at `Cron Job`

Answer (score 1):

set cron job for that, for example like this:

```
#shell$ crontab -e
*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php -f /path/to/your/script.php
```

above line will cause script to run every two minutes.

you can read more about cron [here](http://www.manpagez.com/man/5/crontab/) or on [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron), google for more or read man page on your machine